# JavaScript Check length of String and if it's longer than 4, save variable in different variable

Tags: javascript, servicenow

I am currently learning a bit.
In one script I get a number which lenghts usually is 4.  In rare cases it can be a 8 digit number.
If it's 8 digits long I need to save it in a different variable.

So I get my variable, lets call it `mynumber`.

Now I printed `mynumber.length` which is mostly 4. If it is greater than 4 I want to store my original variable in `mynumber2` and delete it from `mynumber`.

What's a good way to achive that?

Comment: Show the code please so we can help you.

Comment: You already have the pseudocode, just convert it.

Comment: What does the tag servicenow have to do with the question? For somebody with > 1k rep I would expect more from both the question format as the tags used

Comment: I will update in a minute, I use servicenow server side scripts. which is basically javascript + glide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this;

```
myNumber = 1234;                   // Or whatever is the value
if(myNumber.length > 4)           // If length greater than 4
   myNumber2 = myNumber;

myNumber = undefined;             // If you want to delete it from original number variable

delete myNumber;                  // If you want to delete the original number variable
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var x = 12345;
var mynumber = 0;
var mynumber2 = 0;
(x.toString().length > 4 ? mynumber2 = x : mynumber = x);
console.log(mynumber + ' - '+ mynumber2);
```